# Angularjs 2 rc 5 form Custom Validation

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a custom validation to my form when I include the ' [(ngModel)]="form" ' in my form tag I start getting the error.

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in        pages/login.component.html:8:7
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name  attribute must be set or the form
  control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

  Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
  Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

But I have included the name attribute in the input. I am ok to make the input a standalone model  if I could add a custom validation to an individual element in the class.

```
   <div class="loginFormContainer fixedContainer">
       <form [(ngModel)]="form" #loginForm="ngForm">
           <div class="loginTitle">
            Sign in to xxxx
           </div>
          <div>
                <span class="fieldLabel">Login name</span>
          </div>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" #name="ngModel"  class="inputField medium" > 
        <div>
```

Typescript code

```
export class LoginComponent  
 {
    form: ControlGroup;
    model = new Login("", "");

   constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private loginServ : LoginService,
      fb:FormBuilder
      ){
         this.form = fb.group({
         user:['', Validators.required],
         pass:['', Validators.required]
       });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For reasons I don't understand ngModel does not play nicely here anymore.

Try using formControlName="name" instead